# How to sign rawtransaction with private key

Tags: raw-transaction, java

How to sign raw transaction with private key.
this is my raw transaction :

`0200000001fcd54594bba82795afa84ebf500b3944546117c9371e951fc4539e7455ebafb20000000000ffffffff01b8f902000000000017a914b4e6b1471691d9e9e54cd19d39c8565bcadeb3338700000000`

which is made by bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction .

That raw transaction made in server.

And I want to sign this raw transaction in my local PC.
How do I sign that with private key?

Please let me know with the sample code.
My language is java.

Very Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java? Sign it with the program that created the raw transaction, bitcoin-cli.

With signrawtransactionwithwallet.

Or with signrawtransactionwithkey (0.17.0 RPC)

signrawtransactionwithkey "hexstring" ["privatekey1",...] ( [{"txid":"id","vout":n,"scriptPubKey":"hex","redeemScript":"hex","amount":value},...]

take txid,vout,scriptPubKey from an online explorer, live.blockcypher.com

redeemScript should be blank.

"raw transaction" "["priv key"]" "[{"txid":"the taxid","vout":the vout integer,"scriptPubKey":"from the explorer","redeemScript":"","amount":the amount}]"

after sign, if want to call sendrawtransaction, if the tx id is not synced will be "Missing Inputs"(in dogecoin-1.10.0 executed) ; or if wallet is offline or if started with -noconnect, then broadcast the transaction online like here https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/pushtx/

More info to deal with a -noconnect and no synced data situation: [How to send bitcoin from an offline Bitcoin Core that doesn't have a synced balance?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89962/how-to-send-bitcoin-from-an-offline-bitcoin-core-that-doesnt-have-a-synced-bala/101433#101433)

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer. This is Good. I had to do this at offline, So I thought I should do it using some programming which I'd have to made. But your way is very good and works.